# How to design a Button with an icon or pict in Racket?

Tags: user-interface, button, racket, pict

I want to do Buttons and so to look nicer when doing windowing in Dr Racket. I did not found an example how to do it and where are icons stored.

Isabel

Answer (score 0):

You can load a bitmap and use it as the label argument when making a new button%:

```
#lang racket/gui

(define frame (new frame% [label ""]))
(define button-icon (read-bitmap "path/to/image"))
(define button (new button% [label button-icon] [parent frame]))

(send frame show #t)
```